# Prometheus different results, same pod

Tags: kubernetes, containers, prometheus, promql, cadvisor

I have some trouble in understanding why I get multiple results for the same pod in Prometheus/Grafana.

I'm trying to get cpu usage through `rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace=~".+-test", pod=~"my-server-.+", image!~"|.*pause.*", container!="POD"}[5m])`.

The `container` label excludes the results with the `POD` string. I found that those refers to the *pause container* which holds namespace and other things before the container starts.

However I get pause containers in the `image` label. So I excluded them from that label.

Then I found some containers without the `image` label and I excluded them inserting an or (`|`) in the `image` label.

In some cases the cpu usage of the container without the `image` label is lower than the one of the "correct" container (the one with the correct `image` and `container` labels) and in other cases it is very similar, but never the same.

Example:

[Server 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKfMI.jpg)

[Server 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVRzF.jpg)

I would like to understand what are those containers and what they refer to.

PS. the metrics are from `cadvisor`.

Comment: Try this query: `rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace=~".+-test", pod=~"my-server-.+", container!="POD", container=~".+"}[5m])`. Tl;dr: CPU usage is available at several resolutions (container, pod, QoS class) and this query effectively eliminates everything except containers that you defined explicitly. `!="POD"` removes pause containers and `container=~".+"` means "not empty". No resolution besides per container has this label.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, your query works as expected. What do you mean with QoS Class?

Comment: There are [three](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#qos-classes) of them and it's just another level in cgroups tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD", container=~".+"}[5m])
```

In short, CPU usage is available at several resolutions (container, pod, [QoS class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#qos-classes)) and this query above effectively eliminates everything except containers that you defined explicitly. `!="POD"` removes pause containers and `container=~".+"` means "not empty". No resolution besides "per container" has this label.

Comment: Does cAdvisor documentation talk in detail about per cAdvisor metric and its several resolutions ? any reference to that will be very helpful...

Comment: @MaheshBabuJ dunno, I haven't read it. I know that cAdvisor takes those values from cgroups and this behavior is caused by how these cgroups are made. For example, there is a cgroup for `burstable` pods (those whose resource limit is above its "requests" value). Under it there are cgroups for each pod of that class. Inside each pod cgroup you have cgroups for each container. And there you have it, cAdvisor just exports them all without filtering.

Comment: Appreciate your response, a follow-up, So does it mean if i want to see pod level metrics (but not at per container level). then i filter with "{container="",pod!=""} and may be i have to top it with {image=""} as well. Because i see 3 types of query results 1) with container!="" 2) container="" and image="" 3) container="" and image!="". In a way here (2) ~= (1) + (3). Here (1) is per container, (3) is for pause container and (2) is i believe at overall pod-level. So we just need to look at (2) type of query results.. Is that understanding correct ?

Comment: @MaheshBabuJ seems correct to me, although in my setup just `{container="",pod!=""}` is enough as there are no entry with an image other than `""` (you can check with `sum by (image) (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="",pod!=""})`)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
[root@xy-5-server19 ~]# ctr -n k8s.io container ls > /tmp/container.list && ctr -n k8s.io task ls > /tmp/task.list && awk 'FNR==NR {dict[$1]=$0;next}{if($1 in dict){$1=dict[$1]" "$2" "$3}print $1}' /tmp/task.list /tmp/container.list|grep 0743c2cea08edfc98c988fac5fa252c0241d3f4cd8cbe152a3d624bd78ccea57
0743c2cea08edfc98c988fac5fa252c0241d3f4cd8cbe152a3d624bd78ccea57    5186     RUNNING docker.io/deepflowce/clickhouse-server:22.8.6.71 io.containerd.runc.v2
[root@xy-5-server19 ~]# ps -ef|grep 5186
101       5186  4249 19 3月31 ?       9-02:15:52 /usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
root     24890 26221  0 17:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 5186
[root@xy-5-server19 ~]# ps -ef|grep 4249
root      4249     1  0 3月31 ?       01:07:23 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id f0120b526865c58dbe7bd33f612b7509a50366174720989562521cc8cea47805 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
65535     4290  4249  0 3月31 ?       00:00:00 /pause
101       5186  4249 19 3月31 ?       9-02:15:55 /usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
root     25548 26221  0 17:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 4249
[root@xy-5-server19 ~]# systemctl status containerd|grep f0120b526865c58dbe7bd33f612b7509a50366174720989562521cc8cea47805
           ├─ 4249 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id f0120b526865c58dbe7bd33f612b7509a50366174720989562521cc8cea47805 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

I guess the non name item is runc process(pid:4249).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).